# Regex expression that matches #tags but not hex codes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a regex expression in JavaScript that will match any string as long as it starts with a space, then an octothorpe(#), then characters. However, I would like this expression to exclude hexadecimal codes.

I have this expression for capturing #tags:

```
/([\s]#[^<\s]+)/g
```

and I have an expression that captures hex codes in the format (#xxxxxx) that my larger program will be receiving them:

```
/(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6,6}\b)/g
```

but I do not know how to put them together so that I end up with matches that are described by the first expression but not by the second.

I'd like to do everything in a single regex statement. If this is not possible, I would like to know of a way to get all non-hex strings that begin with # using a combination of regex and JavaScript functions.  I'm using jQuery and Backbone.js if that helps.

**Extra Credit:**

What is the difference between this :

```
/(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6,6}\b)/g
```

and this:

```
/(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\b)/g
```

I've been using https://regex101.com to write and test my expressions and both seem to give the same results.

Comment: Can you provide test input? What are you trying to match? What are you trying to not match? Extra credit: You can make a regex101.com permalink that shows what you are doing.

Comment: For the Extra Credit : the only difference is: `{6}` is much more beautiful than `{6,6}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second regular expression as a negative look-ahead ( `(?!` ) inside your first:

```
(?:\s|^)(#(?![\da-fA-F]{6}\b)[^<\s]+)
```

I added at the start the possibility to start a string immediately with a hash, without requiring the space.

See [Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/oC3oN1/1)

NB: `{6,6}` is indeed exactly the same as the short-cut for that: `{6}`. As stated on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

> There's an additional quantifier that allows you to specify how many times a token can be repeated.
>
> The syntax is ***{min,max}***, where *min* is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and *max* is an integer equal to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches. [...] Omitting both the comma and *max* tells the engine to repeat the token exactly *min* times.

Comment: Why is it that you have removed the 0-9 piece from the negative expression and how does the solution still work without it?

Comment: Because `\d` is equivalent.